# How can i change TextField underline hover color by theme palette?

Tags: material-ui

> material-ui v1

How can I change TextField underline hover color by theme palette?
I know it possible by [overrides](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498150/8438996), but how it can work for all components by standart palette options? like:

```js
const themeMui = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: lightBlue,
    secondary: blue,
    error: red,
    common: {
      darkBlack: blue.A700,
    }
  }
});
```

What exactly CSS code I want to change:

[image]

Comment: why you want to override using `palette` ?  simply override the class isn't it ? or by adding new class

Comment: Becouse i have a big project and i don`t want do it with each new component

Comment: yes, so you can do this by adding new className in your component. isn't it ?

Answer (score 11):

Hey I realize this is a bit old, but I have been having the same problem. I came up with this. Hope it helps... there docs are not the best on this!

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        color: 'red',
        '&:hover:not($disabled):after': {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        '&:hover:not($disabled):before': {
          backgroundColor: 'red',          // String should be terminated
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how  my theme file look like, Just for details I have added some random colors

```js
import indigo from 'material-ui/colors/indigo';
import grey from 'material-ui/colors/grey';
import {fade} from 'material-ui';
import spacing from 'material-ui/styles/spacing';

export default {
  palette: {
    primary: indigo,
    secondary: grey,
  },
  status: {
    danger: 'orange',
  },
  typography: {
    // Tell Material-UI what's the font-size on the html element is.
    htmlFontSize: 10,
  },
  overrides: {
    MuiInput: {
      underline: {
        color: 'blue',//input color focus of not  
        backgroundColor:"grey",//background color of whole input 
        '&:hover:not($disabled):after': {
          backgroundColor: 'orange',//its when its hover and input is focused 
        },
        '&:hover:not($disabled):before': {
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',//its when you hover and input is not foucused 
        },
        '&:after': {
          backgroundColor: 'blue',//when input is focused, Its just for example. Its better to set this one using primary color
        },
        '&:before': {
          backgroundColor: 'red',// when input is not touched
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 6):

I was still having issues with the above. This setup worked for me to change all options to white. Just a copy and paste from [mui-org/material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/47d25a9e958ce0ae34e8a7c3bf46e7332233d910/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js) removing anything I don't want to effect. You can use it like in the file above, `const theme = createMuiTheme({..})` or as a style class by adding the prop `classes={{underline: classes.cssUnderline}}` to the input.

```css
underline: {
    '&:after': {
      borderBottom: `2px solid #FFFFFF`,
    },
    '&$focused:after': {
      borderBottomColor: `#FFFFFF`,
    },
    '&$error:after': {
      borderBottomColor: `#FFFFFF`,
    },
    '&:before': {
      borderBottom: `1px solid #FFFFFF`,
    },
    '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error):before': {
      borderBottom: `2px solid #FFFFFF`,
    },
    '&$disabled:before': {
      borderBottom: `1px dotted #FFFFFF`,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only css, you can use something like this:

```css
div::after{
  border-bottom: 2px solid white !important;
}
```

This works best if the style sheet is only applied to that page, otherwise, any div with an `::after` in your entire application will now have a border.